# How to send a request to android server without ip address

Tags: java, android, webserver, android-applicationinfo

I am a newbie in android app development & I have developed an android application which will start a web server and I want to request that server without providing my IP.

**For example :**

This is, what I type in a browser. Now localhost is not working.

```
("http://localhost:8000/api/items/1/");
```

If I provide my ipaddress instead of localhost, it works.

Is there an equivalent to localhost?

Comment: An Android app that starts a web server? And that web server runs on the same device as the app?

Comment: yes, that app will start server in the android device where its installed

Comment: 'without providing my IP. '. You do not have to provide your IP to the server. Instead you should know the IP of the server.

Comment: Then localhost should work. And 127.0.0.1. But only if you use a browser on the same device.

Comment: in url - if i replace localhost with my phone ip , i'm getting expected responce. but when i request with localhost , i'm getting response like webpage not found.

Comment: So i wanted to know , is localhost applicable for android devices also or only emulator ? and is there any other dependencies to make localhost work for android device?

Comment: since server is in the device , ip of the server and device ip is same

Comment: You have not reacted to my comment 'but only if you use a browser on the same device'. You should make clear what you are doing first.

Comment: i'm using browser in same device

Comment: Well than you know my answer already. Both localhost and 127.0.0.1 should work. Did you try the latter? Why dont you react on that comment?

Comment: maybe you can check the android device hosts file.  And add  `127.0.0.1 localhost` if there is not  exist.